# Are Pokemon from eggs better in any way?

Tags: pokemon-go

Will a pokemon that I have evolved have higher CP/CP CAP than one of the same pokemon that I have found in the wild? Will a pokemon from an egg have higher CP/CP CAP than one in the wild?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4twea5/hatched_pok%C3%A9mon_have_higher_ivs/) on [/r/TheSilphRoad](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/) by [/u/Shaeress](https://www.reddit.com/u/Shaeress), Pokemon hatched by eggs tend to have improved IVs. This means that they will usually have a higher CP cap than Pokemon caught naturally.

[/u/transphenomenal](https://www.reddit.com/u/transphenomenal) plotted the data, in [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4twea5/hatched_pok%C3%A9mon_have_higher_ivs/d5kvul9). The following is a roughly normally-distributed graph for naturally caught Pokemon, where 100 indicates a perfect IV Pokemon, with the highest possible CP cap, and 0 indicates a perfectly bad IV Pokemon, with the lowest possible CP cap.

[image: Caught Pokemon IVs]

This graph shows Pokemon hatched from eggs:

[image: Hatched Pokemon IVs]

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a difference. Every Pokemon of the same type (e.g. every Pikachu, Charmander, Squirtle etc.) Have very similar growth stats. The CP cap on every Pokemon is based on the Trainer his level. Catching a Pokemon with a higher CP simply makes training cheaper.

So far the only difference in growth stats is if the Pokemon is XS or XL which can be see in the Pokemon's detail page. XS increases max HP but decreases max CP, XL does the reverse.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Pokemon from hatched eggs have empirically and experimentally been determined to have higher IVs, which increases the CP cap.

Comment: @Schism - At the time this answer was first posted, we didn't have any hard data to show either way

Answer (score 3):

No, however you are rewarded substantially more for hatching an egg than catching that same Pokemon in the wild - you receive a random amount of stardust that seems to range from about 500-1000 and a random amount of candies (I've gotten from 6 to 21). You also receive more experience.

EDIT: Research by people from TheSilphRoad suggest that Pokemon from eggs actually have higher IV's on average

Comment: I've hatched a bunch of eggs and I think I agree but I'm not 100% positive. One thing about higher IV's on egg Pokemon is wild Pokemon are harder to catch with higher IV/CP, whereas walking is the same "difficulty" no matter what. So the more esoteric/stronger Pokemon can be easier to hatch than catch.

Comment: That's a very interesting point. I only glanced at the "headline" of the research, but I'll take a more careful look when I get more time

Answer (score -3):

Eggs are unique in Pokemon Go as some of the best Pokemon in the game only come from the rarest Eggs. Eggs, as you might guess, can hatch Pokémon. So, Eggs are the best way to Play the game.

Comment: Source for this?

Comment: I would say on the human side, if you have to do a lot of walking normally, then you have an advantage in hatching eggs over catching wild Pokemon. If your situation finds you spending a lot of time near a Pokestop where you can put lures and doing very little walking, then you might have more success catching Pokemon rather than hatching eggs. To maximize either you may have to spend some real money (on either Pokeballs or Incubators, as appropriate).