# Are hatched / starter Pokemon different to caught ones?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I hatch a Pokemon, is it different in any way to one I've caught?

I mean ignoring the variation in stats - is there some fundamental difference, like one has the potential for a higher max CP or something?

Likewise, is my starter Pokemon different or special in any way?

Comment: every Pokemon is special!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Pokemon from eggs better in any way?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274025/are-pokemon-from-eggs-better-in-any-way)

Comment: You've got two questions together in your post. I flagged one as a potential dupe, but it might be better if you edit out the hatched part.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference. Hatched pokemon will only start out with higher CP but the maximum CP should be the same as ones you catch in the wild. Also hatched pokemon will give you more candies when obtained. Your starter pokemon is not special and is quite useless throughout the game. You'll find stronger versions of your starter in the wild and you'll probably just transfer your starter for candy.

Source: Personal Experience.

Comment: Hatched pokemon do not necessarily start with higher cp than caught. It can be higher or lower. You also get stardust upon hatching an egg alongside the additional (significantly more than from catching a pokemon) candies.

Comment: Hatched pokemon almost always starts out with higher CP than ones in the wild.

Comment: @KevinTian I hatched a 14 CP caterpie, but caught at 100+ CP caterpie. I have a feeling you're missing a qualifier to your statement.

Comment: Which is why I said almost always. Just because it has happened to you once doesn't mean the other 90% of the time it isn't higher. Personally I have yet to hatch a pokemon whose CP is lower than my current highest wild pokemon.

Comment: @KevinTian I have had a few hatched Pokemon that were higher than the ones I caught of the same type, I have also had a lot of caught Pokemon that were higher than the ones I had just hatched. Eg. I hatched a 264 Zubat and a 238 Ratatta, previously I had already caught multiple 300+ Zubats, Ratattas, Pidgeys and you name it. For every Pokemon I have hatched (except Sandshrew) I have caught a higher CP one in the 'wild'.

Answer (score 2):

To address the primary question, no, they appear to not be different anD really both are variable in power and stats. However, I would caution this statement by asking what team you are on? Yellow team may have more pronounced hatching powers vs blue has more powerful evolutions vs red might find more powerful in the wild or gain cp faster when leveling up. The game simply needs to be played more to find out these nuances.

What I really wanted to mention though was in regards to the starter pokemon being "useless":

I've been holding onto my starter squirtle in the off chance that there is secret coding that will make it super powerful if I level it up long term in the future. If you know about the evee evolution choice trick then you know that it's a possibility they would do something like that.... and if you transferred yours to the professor then you'll be SOL...check out the evee thing on other forums and you'll get why I'm saying this.

https://m.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4t0cpo/psa_how_to_force_your_eevee_to_evolve_into_your/?ref=share&ref_source=embed&utm_source=mweb_redirect&compact=true

It may not be relevant now, it may never be, but I have a feeling, as a long term ingress player, this game will only get more complex alon with the programming anD secret tricks. There WILL be a reason to have kept it...eventually. which will lead more people to create a second or third account to get a starter starter again most likely. This guy who commented there wasn't any reason is just upset now bc he probably transferred his already and wasn't thinking about the long term :(

I'm a level 22 who refuses to pay to play. I'm all about the smart playing and live in a dense urban environment. I think your first starter could be worth holding onto...just in case. That's just my best advice.

BTW I caught a 488 squirtle yesterday and my highest wild catch was a 1270 arcanine. There are wild evolved charizards around here somewhere too. And my buddy caught a Blastoise. That being said...keep your first! The data is in the system, it will know that was your first...

Comment: That's great, but it doesn't actually answer the question.  Can you edit your answer to address what's being asked, please?

Comment: I was answering the second part of the question as I felt that the previous guy adequately answered it, he was just potentially wrong about calling your starter "useless"

Comment: You're still not answering it.  You're alluding to it in a sideways manner, but nowhere do you directly answer the question.

Comment: There ya go frank, a little more direct for you. Sorry, I'm stoned, just trying to help out :)

Comment: I added a link to the eeveelution trick and also clarified a bit better just now, too. You were right, my original answer was not adequate.

Answer (score 0):

The starters height and weight are both xl meaning its cp will be higher. Not by much but it will be stronger. Xl means boost in power and health and xs is boost in speed of attack rate and dodgeing.

Comment: Starters are not necessary xl. I had an xs with 10cp starter. They are just like any other Pokémon

Comment: Have you got a reference for height and weight correlating to CP? Everything I've seen (including IIRC the research done by TheSilphRoad on reddit) disagrees with this.

Comment: I should of added i took bulbasaur he is xl and xl for height and weight. My girl took squirtle also xl and xl. But anyway. The size compared to cp and other stats is something ive come to realize after reaching lvl 25. Ive read post saying i was wrong. But ive done a lot of different tests on a lot of different pokemon. Heres a post supporting my theory. http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/180967-pokemon-go/73992556

Comment: P.s. there is the occasional pokemon that doesnt follow this theory 1\10 odds of finding it though. Just thought id throw that in there.